# How to remove dipstick tube from 2003 Acura TL?

Tags: maintenance, scheduled-maintenance

In the course of changing the timing belt in my 2003 Acura TL, my Hayne's manual says to remove the dipstick tube.  The manual says that this is accomplished by removing one bolt.  I removed the bolt, but the dipstick tube still seems to be connected to the engine at the bottom somehow, though it wiggles around somewhat.

Should I wiggle and pull it to free it, or is that likely to damage the components?  What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

If the manual says there is only one bolt, it might simply be stuck. Can you wiggle it, and it rotates? Sometimes the just have some build up that is making it difficult to remove.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the dipstick tube might be [easier to remove on a warm engine](http://honda-tech.com/showthread.php?t=2348332) than a cold one.

From looking at [this photo series](http://tl.acurazine.com/forums/showthread.php?t=695821), I can understand why you're confused: it's a single bolt, it seems like it should pop right off.  If you aren't already in pieces all over the garage, I'd recommend trying to warm up the engine oil and see if it feels like it'll come free.